# Styling dovetail box - tails or pins on front side

Tags: joinery, boxes, dovetail

I am building a box to hold some of my router bits and will use dovetail joints for the vertical sides. I am not sure what to put in front, the tails or the pins.

Aside from mechanical considerations, what are the styling considerations?

So: **Tails in front or pins in front?**

Comment: +1 on what @GernBlanston said. It's purely down to whatever you think looks best. If if you make the tails and pins approximately equal sizes it looks quite similar either way! Another option of course is to use half-blind dovetails and then you don't have to choose :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just an aesthetic decision, it comes down to what you think looks better. For my money, pins are more visually interesting than tails, so I'd face the pins forward (meaning tails are cut into the front and back, pins are cut into the sides).

Comment: So I understand that there is no mechanical concerns on a box regarding the front part. Thanks!